# Every time <br> when needed

Tags: php, html

A part of my HTML  looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of text (lines of code)]

Now of course I want some of this text to go to a new line. I can put `<br>` after each line, but I was wondering whether there is a better/easier way to do it because it could be pretty annoying with long text like this. Like could I use a `foreach` for this or something?

Comment: `nl2br()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

Comment: Is this a screen shot of the html?! Consider copying and pasting it in instead

Comment: Is this a question about the quoted code being generated programmatically without new lines? If so I think I misunderstood

Comment: @RichardTingle Yeah I just copied code into my php and it just looked as a regular code, but when I run it, it is just 1 big line. it's too long to just use </br>. That was my question. How to easily just present it as it is in my php file shown.

Comment: Ahh I see, the screen shot is probably fine then. The -1 (not from me) may have been because this isn't super clear

Comment: @RichardTingle Well I got 3 working answers and 1 working comment.. They understood me. And yeah the screenshot wasn't a screenshot of the actual code :P but the text that's within.

Comment: I'm just trying to give helpful criticism as per [your meta question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197251/question-ban-what-for)

Comment: @RichardTingle yeah I know, but people here are giving away downvotes way more often than upvotes. Kind of sad.

Comment: Someone even favorited this and still -3.

Comment: @RichardTingle I think i just got downvoted because I turned my image into code... :S We made it alot worse -.-

Comment: @loko quite possibly, as I said I was working under the assumption that the code was causing the problem rather than the code *is* the problem.  Under that assumption I was expecting nicely formatted code rather than a single horrific line

Comment: @RichardTingle Yeah well now I'll never be able to ask again xd.

Comment: Either take people's advice about clarifying your questions or don't. Goodluck and goodbye

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add your text into `pre` tag:

```
<pre>
.. your text
</pre>
```

and you do not need add `br` after each line.

Answer (score 1):

As it seems to be a portion of code, I suggest to use SyntaxHighlighter. You will not care neither about indentation nor line numbers. See the official website [here](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
<p style="word-wrap: break-word;width:40px"> your content</p>
```